# Detect whether Acrylic Brush is Supported in the device or not

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, acrylic-material

> As per Microsoft's Documentation,
>
> Acrylic automatically adapts its appearance for a wide variety of
>   devices and contexts.
>
> In High Contrast mode, users continue to see the familiar background
>   color of their choosing in place of acrylic. In addition, both
>   background acrylic and in-app acrylic appear as a solid color
>
> ```
> When the user turns off transparency in Personalization settings
> When battery saver mode is activated
> When the app runs on low-end hardware
> ```
>
> In addition, only background acrylic will replace its transparency and
>   texture with a solid color
>
> ```
> When an app window on desktop deactivates
> When the UWP app is running on phone, Xbox, HoloLens or tablet mode
> ```

I have two queries regarding Acrylic Brush.

1) **Is it possible to detect when acrylic brush is disabled for low end devices?**

2) **Is there any event to subscribe enable/disable acrylic brush by user?** Since there's a setting available to toggle acrylic brush in all apps.
[image]

PS: I am not trying to use fallback color.

Comment: For devices which don't have acrylic brush support ( either disabled or not supported) the acrylic brushes have a fallback color defined for each of them..in case you are defining your own acrylic brush you need to specify your fallback color if you want to override the default fallback color ..

Comment: Yes there is indeed a fallback value. What i'm trying to do is to load a different theme dictionary if it is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Transparency effect mode can be checked with the help of UISettings.AdvancedEffectsEnabled bool value.

There's also an event UISettings.AdvancedEffectsEnabledChanged to subscribe for changes in the transparency mode setting.

```
    UISettings settings = new UISettings();

    private bool _IsTransparencyEnabled = settings.AdvancedEffectsEnabled;

    settings.AdvancedEffectsEnabledChanged += settings_AdvancedEffectsEnabledChanged;

    private void settings_ColorValuesChanged(UISettings sender, object args)
    {
        settings = (UISettings)sender;
        _IsTransparencyEnabled = settings.AdvancedEffectsEnabled;
        //TODOD: Do other necessary actions when transparency has changed.
    }
```